# Openstack Swift logging for temp url and Cross domain

Tags: python, cors, openstack, openstack-swift

We have our own private cloud where I have installed OpenStack Swift. I have a working node (proxy and storage) that allows me to store and retrieve if I use the openstack and swift python cli to store and retrieve files. Additionally I am able to use the python API on a remote machine to store and retrieve files.

The root of my question is how to debug temp url and crossdomain filter issues. Is there a way to turn on detailed debug logging for these filters?

I have the default logging set to

```
log_name = swift
log_facility = LOG_LOCAL0
log_level = DEBUG
```

The situation I am trying to troubleshoot is as follows. When I try and use temp url and cross domain (for CORS), I get a 401. I debugged the code and it appears to be a invalid HMAC error. Based on research, this appears to be a date time issue where the client and the server have missed matched times. However both are running the ntpd service so the time should be in sync.

For CORS, it appears that preflight OPTIONS request is succeeding. The subsequent PUT is failing with a 401....

`"No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://blahost' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 401.`" 
The strange part is the OPTIONS request is returning "access-control-allow-origin" instead of 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'... the case is off.

Preflight request:

```
OPTIONS /v1/AUTH_99cf99f26aaa4b2c923806231b03334c/436/88b6d895-6dbf-4f29-904d-96c9b7959016?temp_url_sig=4a953c34372e37b2a22bb31fb0581a7eb7f02cee&temp_url_expires=1441508891 HTTP/1.1
Host: 23.253.200.41:8080
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Access-Control-Request-Method: PUT
Origin: http://blahhost
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.157 Safari/537.36
Access-Control-Request-Headers: accept, content-type
Accept: */*
Referer: http://blahost/binder/436/site/419/folder/17560/file
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
```

Preflight Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
access-control-allow-origin: http://blahost
access-control-allow-methods: HEAD, GET, PUT, POST, COPY, OPTIONS, DELETE
access-control-allow-headers: content-type, accept
Allow: HEAD, GET, PUT, POST, COPY, OPTIONS, DELETE
Content-Length: 0
X-Trans-Id: tx9e359777dfb94148858cd-0055eba012
Date: Sun, 06 Sep 2015 02:08:18 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
```

Subsequent PUT request(notice it is missing the Access-Control-Allow-Origin)

```
PUT /v1/AUTH_99cf99f26aaa4b2c923806231b03334c/436/88b6d895-6dbf-4f29-904d-96c9b7959016?temp_url_sig=4a953c34372e37b2a22bb31fb0581a7eb7f02cee&temp_url_expires=1441508891 HTTP/1.1
Host: 23.253.200.41:8080
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 16231
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Accept: */*
Origin: http://blahost
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.157 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/pdf
Referer: http://blahost/binder/436/site/419/folder/17560/file
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
```

I would appreciate any advice on how to troubleshoot.

Thanks
Greg

Comment: This seems similar to my issue but I believe my issue revolves around the signature being generated in JS.  Do you find any headway with this issue maybe it would help my situation.

Comment: Please make sure the CORS and tempUrl middleware is configured to be in the proper order.. CORS first. 

Also make sure the tempURL key is being set properly prior to attempting to create the tempUrl. I had to check the actual database for the account via MySQL command line.